# how to handle interactive shell in fabric python

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking, fabric

1.after executing expect('OPR>','show alef-users') it go to infinite means it 
  run continuesly.

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.context_managers import settings
from ilogue.fexpect import expect, expecting, run

prompts = []
prompts += expect('Username:','kirti')
prompts += expect('Password:','kirti')
prompts += expect('OPR>','show users')
prompts +=expect('OPR>','exit')
env.password = "kirti@123"
with cd('/home/kirti/opr'):
with expecting(prompts):
run('./kirti', combine_stderr=False)
```

Comment: What's your current code?

Comment: when i run this code then it go in infinite means it go again an again expect('OPR>','show opr-users) it doesn't go to next expect('OPR>','exit')

Comment: You should simply add your code to the body of your question, via the `edit` link.  It's hard to make heads or tales when it's this malformed.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric >= 1.9 allows to handle multiple prompts at the same time, in a single `with` clause: you just have use Fabric's `settings` function, and feed it with a dict; the keys will be the questions, and the values will be the answers. In your case, it will look like :

```
with settings(prompts={'Username:':'admin', 
                       'Password:':'admin', 
                       'OPR>':'show alef-users', 
                       'OPR>':'exit'}):
    run('./go_opr_cli', combine_stderr=False)
```

My answer is inspired by [that section](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.9/usage/env.html#prompts) of Fabric's official documentation. It worked very well for me, but make sure, when writing the dict's keys, that you respect the number of spaces between the last character of the question and the cursor, in the command line, otherwise it will fail.

*Example:* The last prompt is 'OPR>'. If you see in the regular Linux CLI, that there is one space between 'OPR>' and the cursor, then the key should be 'OPR> '

Comment: small typo in your prompts dictionary, there should be  a colon between the key and value

Comment: Two entries with the same key in the same dictionary? What is that supposed to mean? Only the last of these will actually exist in the dictionary.